# What is the difference between DigitalClock and TextClock in android?

Tags: android, time, clock, digital

Currently I am using Digital Clock. It is taking the mobile time format 12 hr or 24 hr. But for my requirement I thought of using TextClock now to always display the time in 12 hr format.

There is set parameter available in TextClock to set the time format. The xml parameter is format12Hour. And one more thing is TextClock is supported from andriod api 17. What will happen for the api less than 17.

Please kindly share me your option to use the Textclock for my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DigitalClock` is for API-16 and below, `TextClock` is the new widget for API-17 and above:

> DigitalClock
>
> This class was deprecated in API level 17.
>   It is recommended you use TextClock instead.

You should simply use 2 XMLs to support both:

*layout/yourlayout.xml* with `DigitalClock` widget and *layout-v17/yourlayout.xml* with `TextClock` widget.

Comment: Yes clear and Always I want to display 12 hour format. Ho to do that?

Comment: That is another question. And *everything* is clearly explained in the official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

Comment: I tried by setting the 12 hr format. But still  it is displayed in 24 hr format which is same as phone time format. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry but you should open another question for that. This one seems answered to me (feel free to validate).